# Stuck/Spinning Bolt Screw

Tags: screws, removal, bolts, stuck

Some time ago I had a handyman install a pull-up bar with some "M10 x 75" bolt screws that came included with the pull-up bar.

When I try to take the bolt screw off to remove the pull-up bar, the bolt screw just spins. If I try tightening it, it also just spins.

I have tried using vise-grip pliers to pull the bolt screw away from the wall while I turn the bolt screw counterclockwise, but I have made no progress here. Any advice would be welcome.

[image]

[image: Screw]

Comment: The bolt you show in the 2nd picture is not an M10 bolt, it's a lag screw (or lag bolt). Does the one you're struggling with look exactly like that (large widely spaced threads) or does it have much finer & closely spaced threads?

Comment: @brhans It looks exactly like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I have had success using a jemmy bar (or crow bar) to "load" the bolt while turning it with a spanner or socket, this gives much more pull than just pulling with pliers.